# Is the power consumption of field effect transistors lower than that of bipolar transistors, and why?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, homework, jfet, bipolar

Is the power consumption of field effect transistors lower than that of bipolar transistors, and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power consumption MOS vs BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312215/power-consumption-mos-vs-bjt)

Comment: A BJT requires base drive current, when active. A FET requires gate drive current, based on frequency of rate of state-change. If your frequency is low, FETs require almost zero gate current and a BJT cannot compete with that. If your frequency is high, BJTs don't change much but the FET will increasingly require more and more until it is higher than a BJT. So your question cannot be directly answered. There isn't one answer.

Comment: @NStorm : the link of question is indeed useful.

Comment: But actually, the answer of @jonk gives much useful informations.